# Two simultaneous requests cause 401 (cookie JSESSIONID?)

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, cookies

When I send requests at the same time I receive 401. What could be wrong?

```
Request URL: http://localhost:5000/api/***
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 401 
Date: Mon, 01 Nov 2021 23:20:08 GMT
Cookie: JSESSIONID=D0A23516553FAA68121D9013A986D62C

Request URL: http://localhost:5000/api/***
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 401 
Date: Mon, 01 Nov 2021 23:20:08 GMT
Cookie: JSESSIONID=D0A23516553FAA68121D9013A986D62C
```

Comment: What do you mean by at the same time, is it working individually? 401 status code 
 says you are Unauthorized to access this resource. So May be you have not logged into system and trying the API directly. Try login first and then call the API with necessary information

Comment: Unfortunately this is a different case, the requests worked and were authorized. Everything was fine until we added to make the button click send two requests at the same time, the requests still work if you send them independently of each other.     
I suspect that since the requests are sent instantly, they can't keep up with changing auth-headers/cookies/JSESSIONID